# Outlook Exchange account view raw NDR report

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, smtp

Office 365 / Outlook I am interested in viewing the raw NDR report from a bounced message.  The NDR from postmaster seems to be a special type of email, or Outlook is treating it differently.  The NDR in Outlook shows a paperclip icon, but there are no attachments in the message that I can figure out how to open.  I recall in previous versions of Outlook the NDR had two attachments.  The original message, and a small plain text NDR report that had useful info from the SMTP server such as Error Code / Diagnostic Information for Administrators
e.g.)

```
Remote Server returned '< #5.7.1 smtp;550 5.7.1 Invalid Mailprotector recipient...>
Remote Server returned '< #5.5.0 smtp;553 Invalid recipient ..>
```

etc...

It also used to work on iPhone iOS Mail app, which let me open the mime-attachment, but that stopped working in the last couple years too.

So how can I see this the diagnostic info, NDR Error code, etc... these days from the client side? Thanks.

Comment: Any updates on your issue?

Comment: @JoyZhang I think it was a red herring, it was relaying through an outgoing email gateway (appliance with postfix) which was removed around the time this started.  The old style of NDR was from a postfix server, and the newer style without details is IIS6 SMTP which from what I can tell does not have support for detailed NDRs

Answer (score 0):

How do these NDR report look like? Could you post more details for further troubleshooting?

What is the file type of the NDR?

You could check the detailed information of [Non-delivery report in the Security & Compliance Center](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/mfi-non-delivery-report?view=o365-worldwide), then you could see which side generate the NDR. If the NDR generate in recipients side, you may need seek for help from recipients side.